# Shortest path trough a set of points

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, optimization, big-o

I have a set of points (represented by complex values), and I need to find the shortest path through these. It looks a bit like the travelling salesman problem, but I can't seem to find (or understand) a solution that isn't in O(n!). I know how to compute short enough solutions in O(n^3), O(n²), but I wanted to know if it was possible to have THE best one. Thank you !
There's the code I use for a "Short Enough Path"

```
def insert(x,liste,taille):
    max_add = 10**9
    n = len(liste) -1
    for i in range(n):
        test = abs(liste[i] -x) + abs(liste[i+1] - x) - taille[i]
        if test < max_add:
            max_add = test
            i_max = i

    taille[i_max] = abs(liste[i_max]-x)
    taille.insert(i_max+1,abs(liste[i_max+1] - x))
    liste.insert(i_max+1,x)

def sort(x,i=0):
    taille = [0]
    tri = [x[i]]*2
    for y in x[:i]+x[i+1:]:
        inserer(y,tri,taille)
    return tri, taille

def the_best(liste):
    n = len(liste)
    shortest = 10**9
    for i in range(n):
        a,b = sort(liste,i)
        if sum(b) < shortest:
            back = a,b
    return back
```

`
Of course the "the_best" function is in O(n^3) so I usually use the "sort" function only
The list called "taille" is built like this:

taille[i] = abs(liste[i] - liste[i+1])

liste[-1] = liste[0]

Comment: Since you recognise that it's the travelling salesman problem, how do you expect an efficient algorithm to find the exact answer?

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is not complete. If you need to find the shortest path through points, you need to have the length of the path between the points. What is the complex number associated to each point used for ? You don't explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand in your description, this is indeed the TSP problem. It is a well-known **NP-hard** problem, and as such an *efficient* algorithm to solve it does not exist (even if it does, we don't know of it yet). It's one of the famous open problems in Computer Science.

Indeed, do give it a try to solve it, but do not hold your breath :)

General reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

You may also want to give a quick read to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem